# wget exclude list of filenames

Tags: bash, wget

I need to fetch data from an ftp server with `wget`.  I need it to fetch all files from one directory except for a list of filenames.  So, for example:

```
fetchDir="ftp://user:pass@host/path/to/FileName*.csv.gz"
excludeList="FileName314.csv.gz, FileName271.csv.gz, FileName161.csv.gz"

wget ${fetchDir} --reject ${excludeList} -nc
```

This however gives me an error that looks like this:

```
...
Rejecting ‘FileName000.csv.gz’.
Rejecting ‘FileName001.csv.gz’.
No matches on pattern ‘FileName*.csv.gz’.
--2015-12-08 14:27:28--  http://filename314.csv.gz/
Resolving filename314.csv.gz (filename314.csv.gz)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘filename314.csv.gz’
```

How do I change my code such that it accepts my rejects?

Comment: The script seems to be ok, but the above logging does not match the script.

Comment: The logging was very long.  Though I've double checked, and the logging seems consistent with the correlating error when I run it.  Were doesn't it match?

Comment: I cannot exactly reproduce your situation, but my test (`wget 'ftp://localhost/pub/NetStreamer/*.tgz' --reject 'NetStreamer-0*.tgz, NetStreamer.tgz' -nc`) works. What I find strange in your output is the fact that it tries to connect to `http://filename314.csv.gz/`. Can it be that there are files with spaces or asterisks present on the remote ftp site? It should not bother here, but it never hurts to check.

Comment: @steviethecat. I thought that strange too, but no, it is correct.  I'm working from a network which feels like a practice ground (its convloluted), and I'm also fetching data from a vpn with (obviously) ftp connection.  Could that interfere with wget?

Comment: @steviethecat Dammit, it was the spaces between the commas!!  Bash is too fiddly for my liking :(  Thanks for all the input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `--reject` option requires a comma-separated list. However, your `excludeList` variable includes spaces as well as commas. When interpreting a command, the shell carries out [word splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting) **after** the shell variables have been expanded.

This results in only the first filename pattern being treated as an argument for the `--reject` option; the remaining list members will be parsed as extra URLs. The variable assignment should be changed to:

```
excludeList="FileName314.csv.gz,FileName271.csv.gz,FileName161.csv.gz"
```

Note: the double quotes aren't actually required since there are no special characters in the string.

Comment: Thanks.  Damn fiddly bash. But I think I'll keep quotes, if only for readability and my sanity.  And it never interferes, does it?

Comment: @Roman Correct. Quoting strings does no harm and can be more readable (which is why I retained them for my answer). BTW, I've also edited my answer to include a very useful link on word splitting.